# Color fading in contact with air over period of time

Tags: materials, color

I am a product designer and I am wondering if there is a pigment or ink that is able to fade over time by staying in contact with air? I am designing a label that  should change color after approximately 6 months, in order to detect that the product is expired. What type of support is needed? I found these type of examples:

http://pubs.acs.org/subscribe/archive/ci/31/i02/html/02haas.html

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: As a side note, if you're a product developer, and hope to eventually come up with a product that you or your company would be interested in patenting, be care what you post here, as this is a public forum, and including too many details may constitute public disclosure.

Comment: Maybe look for something that reacts water vapour slowly? This wouldn't work if your product will be in a low humidity, cold storage situation for a significant period of time.

Comment: In its current form, th question may be voted as *too broad* for ChemSE.  If you were still interested in a solution based on slowly advancing chemical reactions, perhaps a platform like innocentive (https://www.innocentive.com/) represents an alternative.

Comment: Whether the color change is caused by chemical or physical phenomena, the rate of change almost certainly would be influenced by external factors, such as temperature or humidity during storage.